# How to change default List View Web Part?

Tags: 2010, web-part, list-view

I created a web part for show list item of special list.

I want show this web part instead of default list view.

How to change default List View Web Part ?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to change view, you will be able to do it by editing Web Part and and just change view in properties window.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you achieve your requirement 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2008/03/15/programmatically-create-a-view-custom-view-of-a-list-and-change-the-view.aspx